# Can't install virtualenvwrapper on OSX 10.11 El Capitan

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, osx-elcapitan

I recently wiped my Mac and reinstalled OSX El Capitan public beta 3. I installed pip with `sudo easy_install pip` and installed virtualenv with `sudo pip install virtualenv` and did not have any problems.

Now, when I try to `sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper`, I get the following:

```
Users-Air:~ User$ sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper

The directory '/Users/User/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/User/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting virtualenvwrapper
  Downloading virtualenvwrapper-4.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv-clone in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Collecting stevedore (from virtualenvwrapper)
  Downloading stevedore-1.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pbr<2.0,>=1.3 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from stevedore->virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): argparse in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from stevedore->virtualenvwrapper)
Collecting six>=1.9.0 (from stevedore->virtualenvwrapper)
  Downloading six-1.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: six, stevedore, virtualenvwrapper
  Found existing installation: six 1.4.1
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (six) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling six-1.4.1:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 223, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 299, in run
    root=options.root_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 640, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 726, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 125, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 314, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-tTNnKQ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

As the issue seems to be with the `six` package, manually trying to uninstall it with `sudo pip uninstall six` results in the same error. The output suggests using the `-H` flag as well, but I still get pretty much the same error:

```
Users-Air:~ User$ sudo -H pip install virtualenvwrapper
Collecting virtualenvwrapper
  Downloading virtualenvwrapper-4.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv-clone in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Collecting stevedore (from virtualenvwrapper)
  Downloading stevedore-1.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pbr<2.0,>=1.3 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from stevedore->virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): argparse in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from stevedore->virtualenvwrapper)
Collecting six>=1.9.0 (from stevedore->virtualenvwrapper)
  Downloading six-1.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: six, stevedore, virtualenvwrapper
  Found existing installation: six 1.4.1
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (six) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling six-1.4.1:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 223, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 299, in run
    root=options.root_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 640, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 726, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 125, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 314, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-fwQzor-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

I have disabled rootless with `sudo nvram boot-args="rootless=0"`, and this has had no effect. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3165

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can manually install the dependencies that don't exist on a stock 10.11 install, then install the other packages with `--no-deps` to ignore the dependencies. That way it will skip `six` (and `argparse` which is also already installed). This works on my 10.11 beta 6 install:

```
sudo pip install pbr
sudo pip install --no-deps stevedore
sudo pip install --no-deps virtualenvwrapper
```

And no need to disable rootless.

Comment: I just tried it on 10.11.1 and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: This works on 10.13.2 (High Sierra) as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 68):

```
sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper --ignore-installed six
```

Also works