# virtualenv not working on Mac OSX 10.11 El Capitan

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, virtualenv, osx-elcapitan

I try to create a virtualenv but if fails. I searched at Google and at Stackoverflow but I found nothing helpful. Maybe someone can point me to an answer?

Thanks for your help

I'm using:

- python 2.7.10
- virtualenv 13.1.2
- pip 7.1.2
- Mac OSX 10.11 (El Capitan)

Log Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 832, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1004, in create_environment
    install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 969, in install_wheel
    'PIP_NO_INDEX': '1'
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 910, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
```

Comment: You should try reinstalling python. Perhaps try using pyenv and home-brew to assist.

Comment: Take a look here and install a new version of Python: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33659138/996114

Comment: Possible [related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32095725/1699210)

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same thing with El Capitan. With the version updates comes different variation of what how you install it. See below steps to install both pip and virtualenv:

1. Try reinstalling pip by visiting this [Quick tutorial to install pip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yBdZZGPpYxg)
2. Then run this command in your terminal `sudo pip install virtualenv`